# Global Protect and Azure VM

Tags: azure-vm

I would like to connect to Global protect on my azure virtual machine. installation is not an issue. but when I connect to VPN, I get disconnected from VM and when connection comes back global protect is no longer connected.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running into the same problem but only when I use the Azure VPN P2S Gateway. I have other VMs in Azure that do not use the Azure VPN GW and I don't encounter any issues using Global Protect.

I found this article detailing why it's happening and some workarounds. The "Nested Remote Desktop Connection" option worked for me though it's not ideal. I'm reading through the "Configure a Source NAT on the Router" option and trying to figure out how to apply it using the Azure VPN GW.

https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/kCSArticleDetail?id=kA14u000000HAoM

Comment: Nested one makes sense. But I figured it's not worth it. ended up using actual machine